# Adobe Air HTML/Javascript Resize Windows on Load

Tags: javascript, html, air

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adobe Air SDK Resize Window on Page Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378574/adobe-air-sdk-resize-window-on-page-load)

I am making a desktop html based adobe air app with the adobe air sdk. I'm not very good with javascript and html, so could someone please give me some code on how to resize the app window to a certain pixel height and width on the page load? I know what the dimensions are, the window needs to fit a flash file and a html button below it.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe AIR applications use a configuration file (normally named "application.xml" by most AIR developers) where application settings are spec'd. You'll find samples of this config file in your Adobe AIR SDK folder:

1. "descriptor-sample.xml" in the "samples" folder, and
2. "descriptor-template.xml" in the "templates\air" folder

In this file, you'll find the tag "initialWindow", under which are tags "width" and "height". You'll use these to specify the initial page load size of your application window.

There are other settings worth noting, and #2 above will provide you with details on the other tags used to configure an Adobe AIR app.

Comment: Different pages of my app have different sizes

Comment: You said you want to know "how to resize the app window to a certain pixel height and width ON THE PAGE LOAD". And now you're saying a few more things. You'll get better advice/help if you're more specific and clear with your requirements.