# Adobe Air SDK Resize Window on Page Load

Tags: javascript, html, air

I need to resize an adobe air sdk window on an html page to a certain pixel height and width. Not looking for the initial window in the app descriptor. I'm not so good at coding so could someone give me the code? I think it will be a javascript function. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't realize I could just use normal javascript to do this:

```
<body onload='window.resizeTo(width,height)'>
```